# Движок php не принимает GET параметры

Tags: php, get

Доброго времени суток. Такая проблема: нашёл на просторах интернета обёртку движка, которая изначально показалась мне удобна, но когда подошёл к написанию новых модулей, появилась нужда в использовании get-запросов. Привожу код:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' ) $page = 'home';
else{
    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    if ( !preg_match('/^[A-z0-9]{3,15}$/', $page) ) not_found();
}


$CONNECT = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

if ( !$CONNECT ) echo('MySQL error');


if ( file_exists('all/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'all/'.$page.'.php';



else if ( $_SESSION['id'] and file_exists('auth/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'auth/'.$page.'.php';

else if ( !$_SESSION['id'] and file_exists('guest/'.$page.'.php') ) include 'guest/'.$page.'.php';

else not_found();
```

Данный отрывок из кода страницы index.php, который отвечает за парс данных из браузерной строки и последующее сравнение с другими условиями, которые подключают страницы.
Когда прописываю ссылку на существующую страницу с абсолютно любым get-запросом, меня перекидывает на страницу 404 (оно и понятно, это видно по коду), если прописываю ссылку на ту же страницу без GET, всё работает, за исключением, соответственно, GET-запросов.

Вопрос такой: что нужно добавить, чтобы заработали get-запросы в строке браузера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Избавьтесь от get параметров, которые в `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` следуют за знаком `?`.

Например так:

```
$page = '/admin?fff=1';
$tmp_arr = explode('?', $page, 2);
$page = $tmp_arr[0];

var_dump($page);
```

В результате на экране:

```
string(6) "/admin"
```

Или так

```
$page = '/admin?fff=1';
$length = strcspn ($page, '?');
$page = substr($page, 0, $length);

var_dump($page);
```

Или так

```
$page = '/admin?fff=1';
$page = strstr($page, '?', true); // PHP 5.3+

var_dump($page);
```

Comment: `strstr('/admin?fff=1', '?', true);` => `/admin` ;) PS: PHP 5.3.0 +

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что нужно. Реализовал так: просто вставил первый способ заместо изначальной функции substr с присваиванием.

Comment: @E_p, вам надо было ответ оформить. А у меня память дырявая :(

Answer (score 0):

**Вот так:**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/')
    $page = 'home';
else{
    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    $length = strcspn ($page, '?');
    $page = substr($page, 0, $length);
    //var_dump($page);
    if(!preg_match('/^[A-z0-9]{3,15}$/', $page)){
        not_found();
    }
}
```